# Net::SSH::Win32Perl hangs

Tags: windows, perl, ssh

Hi I am trying to do a simple ls on a unix box from windows xp machine. It hangs and does not exit also. what could be the issue

```
 use Net::SSH::W32Perl;
 use diagnostics;

    my $host = 'host';
    my $ssh = new Net::SSH::W32Perl($host, debug => 1);
    $ssh->login('username', 'password');
    my $cmd = "ls";
    my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);
    print "$stdout";
    exit;
```

below is the output, notice that it has been able to login using password authentication but its not able to give the output. Why is that?

```
>  C:\>perl winssh.pl
>     WXVM0026: Reading configuration data c:\/.ssh/config
>     WXVM0026: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
>     WXVM0026: Connecting to hp-test, port 22.
>     WXVM0026: Socket created, turning on blocking...
>     WXVM0026: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3p2-hpn
>     WXVM0026: Net::SSH::Perl Version 1.34, protocol version 2.0.
>     WXVM0026: No compat match: OpenSSH_4.3p2-hpn.
>     WXVM0026: Connection established.
>     WXVM0026: Sent key-exchange init (KEXINIT), wait response.
>     WXVM0026: Algorithms, c->s: 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
>     WXVM0026: Algorithms, s->c: 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
>     WXVM0026: Entering Diffie-Hellman Group 1 key exchange.
>     WXVM0026: Sent DH public key, waiting for reply.
>     WXVM0026: Received host key, type 'ssh-dss'.
>     WXVM0026: Host 'hp-test' is known and matches the host key.
>     WXVM0026: Computing shared secret key.
>     WXVM0026: Verifying server signature.
>     WXVM0026: Waiting for NEWKEYS message.
>     WXVM0026: Send NEWKEYS.
>     WXVM0026: Enabling encryption/MAC/compression.
>     WXVM0026: Sending request for user-authentication service.
>     WXVM0026: Service accepted: ssh-userauth.
>     WXVM0026: Trying empty user-authentication request.
>     WXVM0026: Authentication methods that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive.
>     WXVM0026: Next method to try is publickey.
>     WXVM0026: Next method to try is password.
>     WXVM0026: Trying password authentication.
>     WXVM0026: Login completed, opening dummy shell channel.
>     WXVM0026: channel 0: new [client-session]
>     WXVM0026: Requesting channel_open for channel 0.
>     WXVM0026: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
>     WXVM0026: Got channel open confirmation, requesting shell.
>     WXVM0026: Requesting service shell on channel 0.
>     WXVM0026: channel 1: new [client-session]
>     WXVM0026: Requesting channel_open for channel 1.
>     WXVM0026: Entering interactive session.
>     WXVM0026: Sending command: ls
>     WXVM0026: Sending command: ls
>     WXVM0026: Requesting service exec on channel 1.
>     WXVM0026: channel 1: send eof
>     WXVM0026: channel 1: open confirm rwindow 2097151 rmax 32768
>     WXVM0026: input_channel_request: rtype exit-status reply 0
>     WXVM0026: channel 1: rcvd eof
>     WXVM0026: channel 1: output open -> drain
>     WXVM0026: channel 1: rcvd close
```

Comment: What version of perl are you using? http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Net-SSH-W32Perl/ indicates that package doesn't work with any recent versions... I'd recommend getting Net::SSH2 from winnipeg

Comment: Thanks Andrew, Got it working using Net::SSH2. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same issue.  [I found a solution in PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=758068) and here's how I got it to work for me.

1. Make sure you're setting your $ENV{HOME} environment variable if it's not set.  Net::SSH will look in there for configuration items.
2. In Net/SSH/Perl.pm, comment out lines 49 and 50 and replace them with `my $proto_class = $ssh->protocol_class($proto);`

Comment: Joel, thanks for the help. I would not prefer doing the above since I would have to implement the same on each of the installations. I got the thing working using Net::SSH2